# J2ME MIDlet appears in Gallery but not in Applications

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet

I've written a MIDlet with J2ME using Eclipse. To test it, I transfer the MIDlet using a bluetooth connection to my Nokia 6131.

But the MIDlet (or App) just appears in the phone's "Gallery" folder.

How can i move it to the "Applications" folder (where the other J2ME Apps reside)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Nokia PC Suite should solve the problem and install the program into the "Applications" folder/menu.